# How to permanently change Ctrl + C to Ctrl + K in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, centos, stty

I try to use this `stty intr ^K` in order to change `Ctrl + C` to `Ctrl + K` in CentOS 7.

But when I restart my server. It resets to default again.

How can I change it permanently from `Ctrl + C` to `Ctrl + K` in CentOS 7 ?

Comment: Put it in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: You mean add `stty intr ^K` line at the end of `.bashrc` which located at home directory? @AulisRonkainen

Comment: Yes, exactly. It should be ran everytime you launch bash.

Comment: Is there a difference to put it in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc ? Will it work for other accounts such as root? @AulisRonkainen

Comment: There's a slight difference. It is in fact user specific. Put it in `/etc/bash.bashrc` for system wide effect.

Comment: I wrote an answer so that people can find it better. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `stty intr ^K` to your `~/.bashrc`.

If you want to have a system wide effect, you need append that to your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file.